# Convert $(-1.0, 1.0)$ to degrees

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

[image]

I'm trying to convert an analog stick from a game controller into degrees. It gives me a range from $-1$ to $+1$ on the $x$ and $y$ axes. I can get values for $x$ and $y$. If dead right is $0$ degrees how can I find the angle of the red dot in degrees?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the `atan2` function of your favourite programming language. It will compute an expression such as $\arctan(\frac yx)$ for the first quadrant etc.
Also note that the point you drew up has coordinates $-\frac1{\sqrt2}, \frac1{\sqrt2}$ and not $-1,1$, since it's on the unit circle. The corresponding angle will be $\frac{3\pi}4$ in this case.

Per @robjohn's answer, you can also use $2\arctan(\frac y{1+x})$ for $(x,y) \ne (-1,0)$ on the unit circle.

Comment: I chose your answer because of your direction to atan2. I overcame the -1 problem by adding 360 to the result if it is < 0.

Comment: @bwoogie That's okay as long as `atan2` spits out your angle in degrees. Otherwise you must add $2\pi$ or convert to degrees with the factor $\frac{180}\pi$.

Comment: It does! It can also give radians if desired.

Answer (score 2):

Using the arctan function usually needs one to adjust quadrants if $x\lt0$. However, one can use
$$
\theta=2\arctan\left(\frac y{r+x}\right)
$$
where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, to get the angle without quadrant adjustments (unless $x\le0$ and $y=0$, in which case $\theta=\pi$ works).

Comment: N.B. In programming, most languages are equipped with a function called `atan2`, which avoids the divide-by-zero error you might identify above. (Oh, I see now another answer has covered that.)

Comment: @Arkamis: yes. I added a bit about the division by $0$ when $x\le0$ and $y=0$. However, in most cases, this works better than $\arctan\left(\frac yx\right)$.

Comment: Small addition to the `atan2` remark: Convergence of the base algorithm behind this function is much better than that of $\arctan$ since it uses a specialized iterative approach.